# PHP,HTML Need to direct from one form to another form

Tags: php, html

I have written a code to get First name,last name and NIC no. If First name is missing I will show a error call "missing" infront of the textbox. All this thing is working and it will send the information in to the same page.

If first name is missing show the error in the same form which will allow user to refill it. If the user entered information correctly, I need to redirect user to another form. How can I do it?

```
<?php
      $fnameerr="";
      $name="";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
    if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
    $fnameerr="Missing";
    }
}

?>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">

First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
<span class="error" style="color:#FF0000">*<?php echo $fnameerr;?></span>
<br/><br/>

Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br/><br/>

NIC:<input type="text" name="nic" /><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Register"/>

<input type="reset" name="re" value="Reset"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tanx it worked...can I no little more thing??

when I do not enter the first name it will show up the error "missing" but it will reset all the other values.(I entered last name and nic number and not entered the first name.when submitted it shows the error and reset the other values.)can I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect

```
if(empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameerr="Missing";
}
else {
    header("Location: anotherForm.php");
}
```